# Install NewSSHSession offline server - powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to install a posh-ssh on my offline env so i can create ssh connection via powershell.
i went to this website:

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Posh-SSH/2.0.2

seems like it has the files i need inside, but i'm not sure how to install it.
any ideas? or this is the wrong link?

back then i used the following command:

```
find-module PoSH-SSH | Install-Module
```

but now its not working (since im not connected to the internet).

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Scepticalist i made some google and found this article

https://fileinfo.com/extension/nupkg

the following softwares can open this file:

Microsoft Visual Studio with NuGet extension

Microsoft File Explorer

7-Zip

Corel WinZip 23

WinRAR 5

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It;s a comprsssed archive. Just unzip it into a folder called "POSH-SSH".

Place the folder in your modules directory which you can find by typing

```
$env:PSModulePath
```

To install for all users, place it in C:\Program Files\WindowsPowershell\Modules (for 64bit)

Then just Import-Module as usual

Comment: the file called "posh-ssh.2.0.2.nupkg is compressed? i cannot unzip it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that Windows 10 has SSH built in since v1809? An OpenSSH-Client is already installed, you can directly use it by calling `ssh`. There is also an OpenSSH-Server available, but has to be enabled as a feature first.

[MS documentation on enabling OpenSSH-Server](http://web.archive.org/web/20200325080145/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)